# Nonincreasing cdf? Potential error in my textbook..

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Image from Introduction to Mathematical Statistics (7th edition) by Hogg, McKean & Craig:

[image]

I hope I'm not missing something obvious here, but isn't a cdf supposed to be non*decreasing*? If $F$ is a cdf of a random variable $X$ and $x \leq y$ then it must be that $F(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(X \leq y) - P(x < X \leq y) \leq P(X \leq y) = F(y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cdf $F_T(t)$ is indeed nondecreasing as a function of $t$, but here the text is talking about the dependence on the parameter $\theta$, not on $t$.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Crystal clear now, thank you